# Concentric Circles and SunBurst Chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2010, ms-office

Can someone help with the steps to create the below chart in Excel ?

[image]

The table structure is as follows, with the outer circle mapped against 1 column, middle circle mapped against values in 2nd column and the part within this will be colored dark based on the number in the third column, I've handled this with a macro
The problem is I've created this with free form so If I add more rows it doesn't make any difference, I want the circle to be generated dynamically proportionate to the number of rows

[image]

Comment: *I've created macro for this* What part in the code are you having trouble with? You should at least post the code.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you have tried so far and where you are faltering. Example code on how to do this is e.g. here, I'm not sure what else you could need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651195/how-to-format-sunburst-chart-in-vba